# Is MD5 still a viable solution for validating the integrity of files?

Tags: command-line, hashsum, integrity

I read about the MD5 collision and that MD5 is not reliable anymore, however, I'm curious if that applies when we check the integrity of files. I've noticed that tools such as the FLAC/metaflac (Free Lossless Audio Codec) still relies on MD5 for checking the data integrity of music files.

Comment: That depends on what you're afraid of, and details of the file format I don't know, but some file types allow you to append a block without affecting what you can hear/see if you open the file normally. If you're afraid of stray bitflips when downloading a file it's still quite unlikely that the resulting file has the MD5sum yo expect, so for that MD5 is about as useful as ever. If you want to ensure that noone has intentionally tampered with a file, you need to know more.

Comment: I'm just interested in checking the integrity of files on my hard drive. No download. Just check it after a year or two if they still have the same integrity and nothing happened during the period of years.

Comment: Unless you suspect that someone may have tampered with the files on you hard drive, that is like stray bitflips during a download.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even CRC32 is viable because when you hear about collisions for MD5/SHA1, it's about specially crafting data using insane computational capacities to create files with collisions.

That does not apply to single bit errors which can happen for your storage/RAM/IO.

One thing to note though: SHA1/SHA256 for newer CPUs can be a **lot faster** than MD5 because the former is HW accelerated while MD5 is computed.

Simply run `time sha256sum/md5sum large_enough_file` to check it out.

For a cached 4.5GB file here:

```
$ time md5sum *iso
b5a7be560dbd73619945129e52be1b5f  win10.iso

real    0m5.037s
user    0m4.805s
sys 0m0.229s

$ time sha256sum *iso
c90a6df8997bf49e56b9673982f3e80745058723a707aef8f22998ae6479597d  win10.iso

real    0m2.283s
user    0m2.031s
sys 0m0.250s
```

And here's a nice script which I wrote a long time ago to create a file with all my audio files hashsums.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

cd /audio || exit 1

echo -n "Running ... "
find . \(   -iname "*.mp3" -o \
        -iname "*.m4a" -o \
        -iname "*.ogg" -o \
        -iname "*.flac" \
    \) -print0 | sed 's/\.\///' | sed 's/\x0\.\//\x0/g' | sort -z | xargs -0 -n1 ionice -c 3 md5sum | tee /tmp/ALL-`date +%F`.md5 | \
        awk '
            BEGIN{ORS=""}
            {
                out=substr($0, 35);
                print out;
                fflush();
                for (i=0;i<length(out);i++) print "\b \b";
            }
            END{print FNR" all done\n";}
        '
echo " finished"
```

For the `/audio` directory it computes md5 hashes for all the specified file types and produces a file in `/tmp`.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I did not know that flac files compute some "signature". Do you know if it can be used for even limited autocorrection facilities ?

Comment: The embedded blocks hashsum can only tell you whether it is OK or not. FLAC normally skips/mutes such blocks altogether because decoding them may produce junk which you don't want to hear. More on it here: https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,122094.0.html